# Archive posts to a certain year, then have a generic archive tab for older posts

Tags: wordpress

I would like to archive paintings content type by year until 2010, then the rest of the older content types <2010, I would have a generic 'Older Archive' link to list the paintings.

I have already completed the first part:

```
wp_get_archives( array( 
    'post_type' => 'paintings', 
    'type' => 'yearly', 
    'limit' => 4 ) 
);
```

It is displaying as:
2017 | 2016 | ...etc

I would like to list those paintings older than 2010 in one header link.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no offset parameter in `wp_get_archives()`, you can simply change the order to do this.

```
 wp_get_archives( array( 
    'post_type' => 'paintings', 
    'type' => 'yearly', 
    'limit' => 4,
    'order' => 'ASC', ) 
 );
```

As I understand you case, alphabetical order with year are in descending order (default value). If the first archive year is 2006, change `order` to `ASC` will display : 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009.

If you want to reverse these results, you can play with `format` and `echo` parameters and apply your logic to show 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006. But it's another question !

**UPDATE** (from the comments)

You can use the pre_get_post action to change the query

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'so_41494855');

function so_41494855($query){

   if(is_post_type_archive('paintings') && $query->is_main_query()){
       $before = '2009-12-31';
       $after = '2006-01-01';
       $date_query = array(
           'before' => $before,
           'after' => $after
       );
       $query->set('date_query', $date_query);
       $query->set('posts_per_page', '15');
   }
   return $query;
}
```

You will find all details for the WP_Query and the date parameter [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) to adapt you query.

You will need to detect this archive page with a special archive link. I suggest you to see about add_query_var() and [get_query_var()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) and will be add to the public query variables available to WP_Query.

the conditionnal became :

```
if(is_post_type_archive('paintings') && get_query_var('show-paintings') == 'older' && $query->is_main_query()){}
```

Another way to think about this could be clone the custom post type to separate new and old paintings. The conditional to detect the archive page and change the query will became `is_post_type_archive('older-painting')`.

Hope it works & helps !

Comment: Thanks, Benoti. But I would like those from 2009,2008, etc to be grouped as one, without distinction. There will be a header link, 'Older Archive' which lists every post in those years.

Comment: Ok, I didn't exactly understand that, I thought you only want the link to the listing page for each year, so I think you can use a pre_get_posts action to list all post with a date_query in a special archive page.

Comment: Thanks, Benoti. Would you mind detailing the pre_get_posts option with date_query? That would be great.

Comment: Yes I will in few minutes